# what is probability that no two balls of same colour be adjacent in a row if we have $3$ red balls , $2$ white balls , one blue ball ??

Tags: probability

> what is probability  that no two balls of same colour  be adjacent in a row  ,  if we have $3$ red balls , $2$ white balls , one blue ball ??

I tried  to use the complement to find the probability
ie, $1$- p ( two same colour balls be adjacent)

I  sadly  can't find either probability ; i need help for dealing with such ideas 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hint:  first consider the possible placements for the red balls.  then populate the gaps.

Comment: @lulu   can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: There are $6$ slots.  You need to fit three  Red balls with no two next to each other.  That's hard!  There are only a few ways to do it.  List all three and then count the number of ways to populate the blanks.  Then count the total ways to arrange the six balls.  Divide.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to suggest that there were exactly three ways to place the Reds.  That was a typo.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.  How many distinguishable arrangements are there for $3$ red balls, $2$ white balls, and $1$ blue ball?  For the numerator, line up three red balls, then insert the remaining balls so that no two balls of the same colour are adjacent.  Notice that you must place at least one ball between each pair of red balls.